# How to catch the details of the file copy/move event, such as the source file name

Tags: .net, windows, events, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

Just want to write a application to track the relationship between the files in the disk.

We know that FileSystemWatcher can fire evetns when creating, renaming or deleting the file.

But FileSystemWatcher can not tell us the path of the source file.

For example, let's say there is a file `F1` in the `folder1`, and then we copy `F1` to another folder named `folder2`, the new file name is still `F1`. In this case the `FileSystemWatcher` could tell us there is a new file has been created in `folder2`. But it can not tell us the new `F1` is copied from the `F1` in `folder1`, while this information is what we need.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll probably need to monitor both source and target folders, and then try to match the files vanishing from the source with the files appearing in the target, possibly by comparing their names/sizes or even checksums.

Comment: Similar to what @Branko suggested.  If i make a Folder Tree Data structure of Folder1 and Folder2  at time T0 and then do some file Movement and then again create a New FolderTree structure T1 . Now i do compare the Folder 1 tree {T0,T1} and Folder 2 {T0,T2} and Collate the difference .

Comment: In general, you can't obtain this information from the file system. It doesn't know where files come from. That new file in `folder2` could have been created by some process (possibly running on a different computer) that's writing a new file. You *can* monitor known sources and reconcile with files that appear in the target and are subsequently removed from the source. But that will only help on move operations, not copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there is no such operation as "copy a file", as far as the filesystem is concerned.

When you run a file copying command, it actually opens the old file, creates the new file, reads content into memory, writes to the new files, then closes both.  All the filesystem sees are writes; there's no taint-tracking system for determining that the data actually came from another file without modification.

The final step, that differentiates the file copy from writing data to a file normally, is that the metadata of the destination are changed to match the source.  But again, the filesystem doesn't know why you're changing the attributes or which file you're matching them two.

The filesystem only has special awareness of linking and unlinking.  So moving, which consists of "create second link to content; remove first link" is detectable. If copying were implemented as "create new link marked for copy-on-write" then you could discover it, but copy-on-write is not a very popular filesystem feature.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is: you wont have a copy event fired for the folder "f1".

what does trigger the file watch for folder 1 is: updating a file, copy a file from other directory to "f1" or deleting a file.

you can try using two files in "f1"..at the same time you copy the file to "f2" you can update the second file, thus triggering the updating event handler..........

hope this helps....